# How to Seed Data to H2 DB in Spring Boot App with JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, seeding

A little bit of background:

I work on a Spring boot app in a large corporation and we have no control over the Database Schema, table names, and column names. Because of this, our table and column names have no obvious meaning to them.

We are currently seeding data with the schema.sql and data.sql files in the resources directory. This hasn't been working for our team, because of the effort to seed the data with these obscure table and column makes. We often end up looking through our QA server for an account, then writing our code against a QA database.

My question:

- How do I keep the schema.sql and data.sql files, but enable our team to seed data to the H2 database by using a seeder made available by JPA or Spring Data JPA.

  - I found a few examples of using JPA to seed data, but they don't mention where the files should be stored or how the files get called by the Spring Boot app on start up.
- Our application only pulls data, and never inserts, so will I have to override the save function from the JpaRepository in order to accomplish this? Or can I just create an entity, and call the JpaRepository's save function?

Here is an obfuscated example of our account entity and repository:

AccountEntity.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table_Name")
@SecondaryTables({
        @SecondaryTable(name = "Table_Name2", pkJoinColumns = {
                @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ACCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ACCT_ID") }),
        @SecondaryTable(name = "Table_Name3", pkJoinColumns = {
                @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ACCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ACCT_ID") }),
        @SecondaryTable(name = "Table_Name4", pkJoinColumns = {
                @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ACCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ACCT_ID") })
})
public class AccountEntity {

    @Column(name = "ACCT_ID")
    @Id
    private Integer accountIdNumber;

    @Column(name = "SOME_OTHER_COLUMN1")
    private String someOtherColum1;

    @Column(name = "SOME_OTHER_COLUMN2", table = "Table_Name3")
    private String someOtherColum2;

    @Column(name = "SOME_OTHER_COLUMN3", table = "Table_Name4")
    private Integer someOtherColum3;

    ...
}
```

AccountRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountEntity, Integer> {
    public AccountEntity findByAccountIdNumber(Integer accountNumber);

    public List<AccountEntity> findAllByProp1Prop2AndProp3(
            String prop1, String prop2, String prop3);
}
```